# Pure Prolog δλ-Calculus Equality

Tags: prolog, lambda-calculus, logical-purity

It is not so difficult to conceive an appartness relation
for Peano numbers. Its even possible to make a reified
eq/3 predicate like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65427391/502187).

Question is now, whether we can push the boundary and also
implement Scheme `equal?` predicate in a pure and reified manner?
Problem would be for example to realize this reductions,
also known as δ-rule (see Chapter 6 Extensions [here](https://homepages.abdn.ac.uk/k.vdeemter/pages/teaching/CS4026/abdn.only/barendregt94introduction.pdf)):

```
δxx ~~> T 
δxy ~~> F if x and y are not identical
```

In case terms are represented with deBruijn indexes. This
would incorporate alpha conversion into the `equal?` predicate
besides handling lists (trees). Pure can mean intrinsically pure
or operational pure, as defined in the logical purity tag.

Test case is pure intersection with lists (trees), instead only Peano numbers.

Comment: Can you add some test cases in Scheme proper?

Comment: equal? is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17719745/502187

Comment: What's your "pure Prolog", precisely? (Note that [my Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425800/) was about "almost pure" Prolog)

Comment: Pure can mean intrinsically pure 
or operational pure, as defined in the logical purity tag.