# `less/2` relation in Peano arithmetic

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics, logical-purity

This *less-than* predicate in Peano arithmetic

```
less(0, s(_)).
less(s(X), s(Y)) :- less(X, Y).
```

loops when

```
?- less(X, Y), X=s(0), Y=0.
```

Is there a better way to write `less/2` (using Horn clauses only)?

Comment: Note that @false's comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65427391/pure-prolog-peano-number-apartness#comment115687920_65427871 is about a "naive" `neq/2` built on top of `less/2`. It's not pointing out a problem with `less/2`, it's saying that in Prolog the disjunction of two goals that each have infinite solutions will not behave fairly.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie You don't find this behavior of `less/2` troubling on its own?

Comment: Not if you want a `less/2` that is capable of enumerating answers. If it can enumerate answers, then this query says "enumerate all pairs of N, M such that N < M, until you find a pair that I know cannot exist". This enumeration loops *necessarily*. The difference to `neq/2` is important since there, unlike for `less/2`, the assignment `X=s(0), Y=0` *is* a valid solution. When you ask `neq/2` to search for this solution, looping is *unnecessary*.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie I see what you and @ false mean now. Thanks.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie: *"disjunction of two goals that each have infinite solutions will not behave fairly"* counterexample: `( X = f(_) ; X = g(_) )`. This is a disjunction of two goals with infinite solutions each. And it even terminates, thus enumerates the solutions fairly. What needs to be required further is that these infinite solutions can only be described with infinitely many answers. Otherwise I completely agree with you, indeed.

Comment: @false Yes, thank you for the clarification. I try to be precise about solutions vs. answers, but sometimes I'm sloppy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `when/2`. Making it not anymore an infinitely enumerating predicate and still keeping it 100% pure. The `when/2` modifies the S (selection rule) in [SLD-Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLD_resolution), an idea that can be traced back to Alain Colmerauer.

```
less(X, Y) :- when((nonvar(X),nonvar(Y)), less2(X,Y)).
less2(0, s(_)).
less2(s(X), s(Y)) :- less(X, Y).
```

The rewriting of `less/2` into `less/2` and `less2/2` is similary like tabling rewriting. You insert a stub and rename the clause head. But the recursive call in the body is not rewritten, is then a call to the stub again.

You now get steadfastness:

```
?- less(s(s(0)), s(s(s(0)))).
true.

?- less(X, Y), X = s(s(0)), Y = s(s(s(0))).
X = s(s(0)),
Y = s(s(s(0))).
```

And even failfastness and truefastness sometimes:

```
?- less(s(s(_)), s(0)).
false.

?- less(s(0), s(s(_))).
true.
```

Some Prolog systems even provide a table/1 like directive, so that you don't need to do the rewriting, only make the declaration. One such system is SICStus Prolog. In SICStus Prolog, thanks to the [block/1 directive](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/4.0.7/html/sicstus/Block-Declarations.html),

you would only write:

```
:- block less(-,?), less(?,-).
less(0, s(_)).
less(s(X), s(Y)) :- less(X, Y).
```

For a 1980's Paper see for example:

**An Implementation of dif and freeze in the WAM**
Mats Carlsson - December 18, 1986
http://www.softwarepreservation.com/projects/prolog/sics/doc/Carlsson-SICS-TR-86-12.pdf/view

Comment: `less(X, 0)` now flounders.

Comment: Right, you would need even more complex conditions or intermediary predicates.

Comment: The question rather is: is floundering really better than looping?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226429/discussion-between-mostowski-collapse-and-false).