# Pure Prolog Scheme Quine

Tags: prolog, logical-purity, lambda-prolog, occurs-check

There is this paper:

> William E. Byrd, Eric Holk, Daniel P. Friedman, 2012
> miniKanren, Live and Untagged
> Quine Generation via Relational Interpreters
> http://webyrd.net/quines/quines.pdf

Which uses logic programming to find a Scheme Quine. The
Scheme subset that is consider here does not only contain lambda
abstraction and application, but also a little list processing
by the following reduction, already translated to Prolog:

```
[quote,X] ~~> X
[] ~~> []                                      
[cons,X,Y] ~~> [A|B], for X ~~> A and Y ~~> B
```

So the only symbols are quote, [] and cons, besides lembda for
lambda abstraction and bound variables. And we would use Prolog
lists for the Scheme lists. The goal is to find a Scheme
programm Q via Prolog, so that we get Q ~~> Q, i.e. evaluates to itself.

There is one complication, which makes the endeavour non-trival,
[lembda,X,Y] doesn't evaluate syntactically to itself, but is rather
supposed to return an environment closure. So the evaluator would be
unlike the Plotkin evaluator [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65426863/502187).

Any Prolog solutions around? Merry X-Mas

Comment: > Any Prolog solutions around?

Yes, there was some discussion of this problem and solutions on the [comp.lang.prolog mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.prolog/c/81dH-fK4i14).

Comment: The two solutions here don't use sto/1 constraint. But rather in one variant unify_with_occurs_check/2 and and in the other variant occurs_check=true. The later variant beats the former variant in speed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using SWI Prolog with the occurs check turned on here (but `dif/2` skips the occurs check anyway):

```
symbol(X) :- freeze(X, atom(X)).

symbols(X) :- symbol(X).

symbols([]).

symbols([H|T]) :-
    symbols(H),
    symbols(T).

% lookup(X, Env, Val).
%
% [quote-unbound(quote)] will be the empty environment
% when unbound(quote) is returned, this means that
% `quote` is unbound

lookup(X, [X-Val|_], Val).

lookup(X, [Y-_|Tail], Val) :- 
    dif(X, Y),
    lookup(X, Tail, Val).

% to avoid name clashing with `eval`
%
% evil(Expr, Env, Val).

evil([quote, X], Env, X) :-
    lookup(quote, Env, unbound(quote)),
    symbols(X).

evil(Expr, Env, Val) :-
    symbol(Expr),
    lookup(Expr, Env, Val),
    dif(Val, unbound(quote)).

evil([lambda, [X], Body], Env, closure(X, Body, Env)).

evil([list|Tail], Env, Val) :-
    evil_list(Tail, Env, Val).

evil([E1, E2], Env, Val) :- 
    evil(E1, Env, closure(X, Body, Env1_Old)),
    evil(E2, Env, Arg), 
    evil(Body, [X-Arg|Env1_Old], Val).

evil([cons, E1, E2], Env, Val) :-
    evil(E1, Env, E1E),
    evil(E2, Env, E2E),
    Val = [E1E | E2E].

evil_list([], _, []).
evil_list([H|T], Env, [H2|T2]) :-
    evil(H, Env, H2), evil_list(T, Env, T2).

% evaluate in the empty environment

evil(Expr, Val) :-
    evil(Expr, [quote-unbound(quote)], Val).
```

Tests:

Find Scheme expressions that eval to `(i love you)` -- this example has a history in miniKanren:

```
?- evil(X, [i, love, you]), print(X).
[quote,[i,love,you]]
X = [quote, [i, love, you]] ;
[list,[quote,i],[quote,love],[quote,you]]
X = [list, [quote, i], [quote, love], [quote, you]] ;
[list,[quote,i],[quote,love],[[lambda,[_3302],[quote,you]],[quote,_3198]]]
X = [list, [quote, i], [quote, love], [[lambda, [_3722], [quote|...]], [quote, _3758]]],
dif(_3722, quote),
freeze(_3758, atom(_3758)) ;
[list,[quote,i],[quote,love],[[lambda,[_3234],_3234],[quote,you]]]
X = [list, [quote, i], [quote, love], [[lambda, [_3572], _3572], [quote, you]]],
freeze(_3572, atom(_3572)) ;
```

In other words, the first 4 things it finds are:

```
(quote (i love you))

(list (quote i) (quote love) (quote you))

(list (quote i) (quote love) ((lambda (_A) (quote you)) (quote _B)))
; as long as _A != quote

(list (quote i) (quote love) ((lambda (_A) _A) (quote you))) 
; as long as _A is a symbol
```

It looks like the Scheme semantics are correct. The language-lawyer type of constraints it places are pretty neat. Indeed, real Scheme will refuse

```
> (list (quote i) (quote love) ((lambda (quote) (quote you)) (quote _B)))
Exception: variable you is not bound
Type (debug) to enter the debugger.
```

but will accept

```
> (list (quote i) (quote love) ((lambda (quote) quote) (quote you)))
(i love you)
```

So how about quines?

```
?- evil(X, X).
<loops>
```

miniKanren uses BFS, so maybe that's why it produces results here. With DFS, this could work (assuming there are no bugs):

```
?- call_with_depth_limit(evil(X, X), n, R).
```

or

```
?- call_with_inference_limit(evil(X, X), m, R).
```

but SWI doesn't necessarily limit the recursion with `call_with_depth_limit`.

Comment: bfs also supposed to have problems in theory if you have infinite branching at some node. instead some kind of diagonalization needs to be employed.

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse I don't think so. I have OC set to `true` in `.swiplrc`. BFS Prolog engine is what's needed here. `evil(X,Y)` says *"create ALL possible input/out pairs"* -- that's not feasible beyond very short programs.

Comment: @MaxB this Scheme doesn't have `cons`. Are there (small-ish) Scheme quines that don't need `cons`? If there aren't, then no amount of tweaking the search will get you anywhere.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie Thanks! Added `cons`. I'll edit if `call_with_depth_limit(evil(X, X), 6, R).` finds anything -- it's still running.

Comment: I tried to translate the quine found by the other answer into evil's representation and evaluate it, but it doesn't seem to evaluate that expression to itself.

Comment: My version doesn't handle `(lambda x`, only `(lambda (x)`. I didn't know this was allowed. But also `((lambda x (cons x (cons (cons 
  (quote quote) (cons x (quote ()))) (quote 
  ())))) (quote (lambda x (cons x (cons 
  (cons (quote quote) (cons x (quote ()))) 
  (quote ()))))))` actually isn't a quine. It evals to `(((lambda ...` -- **three** parens.

Comment: You can possibly also find a quine for a different language. It might be a different quine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses a little [blocking programming style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65441951/502187). Its not using when/2, rather only freeze/2. There is one predicate expr/2 which checks whether something is a proper expression without any closure in it:

```
expr(X) :- freeze(X, expr2(X)).

expr2([X|Y]) :-
   expr(X),
   expr(Y).
expr2(quote).
expr2([]).
expr2(cons).
expr2(lambda).
expr2(symbol(_)).
```

And then there is a lookup predicate again using freeze/2,
to wait for an environment list.

```
lookup(S, E, R) :- freeze(E, lookup2(S, E, R)).

lookup2(S, [S-T|_], R) :-
   unify_with_occurs_check(T, R).
lookup2(S, [T-_|E], R) :-
   dif(S, T),
   lookup(S, E, R).
```

And finally the evaluator, which is coded using DCG,
to limit the total number of cons and apply invokations:

```
eval([quote,X], _, X) --> [].
eval([], _, []) --> [].
eval([cons,X,Y], E, [A|B]) -->
   step,
   eval(X, E, A),
   eval(Y, E, B).
eval([lambda,symbol(X),B], E, closure(X,B,E)) --> [].
eval([X,Y], E, R) -->
   step,
   eval(X, E, closure(Z,B,F)),
   eval(Y, E, A),
   eval(B, [Z-A|F], R).
eval(symbol(S), E, R) -->
   {lookup(S, E, R)}.

step, [C] --> [D], {D > 0, C is D-1}.
```

The main predicate gradually increases the number of allowed
cons and apply invokations:

```
quine(Q, M, N) :-
   expr(Q),
   between(0, M, N),
   eval(Q, [], P, [N], _),
   unify_with_occurs_check(Q, P).
```

This query shows that 5 cons and apply invokations are enough to produce a Quine. Works in SICStus Prolog and Jekejeke Prolog. For SWI-Prolog need to use for example this [unify/2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65533141/502187) workaround:

```
?- dif(Q, []), quine(Q, 6, N).
Q = [[lambda, symbol(_Q), [cons, symbol(_Q), [cons, [cons, 
[quote, quote], [cons, symbol(_Q), [quote, []]]], [quote, 
[]]]]], [quote, [lambda, symbol(_Q), [cons, symbol(_Q), [cons, 
[cons, [quote, quote], [cons, symbol(_Q), [quote, []]]], 
[quote, []]]]]]],
N = 5
```

We can manually verify that it is indeed a non-trivial Quine:

```
?- Q = [[lambda, symbol(_Q), [cons, symbol(_Q), [cons, [cons, 
[quote, quote], [cons, symbol(_Q), [quote, []]]], [quote, 
[]]]]], [quote, [lambda, symbol(_Q), [cons, symbol(_Q), [cons, 
[cons, [quote, quote], [cons, symbol(_Q), [quote, []]]], 
[quote, []]]]]]], eval(Q, [], P, [5], _).
Q = [[lambda, symbol(_Q), [cons, symbol(_Q), [cons, [cons, 
[quote, quote], [cons, symbol(_Q), [quote, []]]], [quote, 
[]]]]], [quote, [lambda, symbol(_Q), [cons, symbol(_Q), [cons, 
[cons, [quote, quote], [cons, symbol(_Q), [quote, []]]], 
[quote, []]]]]]],
P = [[lambda, symbol(_Q), [cons, symbol(_Q), [cons, [cons, 
[quote, quote], [cons, symbol(_Q), [quote, []]]], [quote, 
[]]]]], [quote, [lambda, symbol(_Q), [cons, symbol(_Q), [cons, 
[cons, [quote, quote], [cons, symbol(_Q), [quote, []]]], 
[quote, []]]]]]]
```

Comment: This quine doesn't seem real: `((lambda x (cons x (cons (cons 
  (quote quote) (cons x (quote ()))) (quote 
  ())))) (quote (lambda x (cons x (cons 
  (cons (quote quote) (cons x (quote ()))) 
  (quote ()))))))` -- it evals to `(((` -- note the number of parens.

Comment: `(lambda (x) ...` is different from `(lambda x` It turns out, both are allowed in Scheme.

Answer (score 0):

One might ask whether an occurs check flag is superior to
an explicit unify_with_occurs_check/2. In the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65511995/502187) with
explicit unify_with_occurs_check/2 we have placed one such call in lookup2/3 and in quine/3. If we use an occurs
check flag, we do not need to manually place such calls and
can rely on the dynamics of the Prolog interpreter.

We removed the explicit unify_with_occurs_check/2 in lookup2/3:

```
lookup2(S, [S-T|_], T).
lookup2(S, [T-_|E], R) :-
   dif(S, T),
   lookup(S, E, R).
```

And also in quine/3, making it less generate and test, and
more constraint logic like. Using the same variable Q twice
acts like a constraint that is pushed into the execution:

```
quine(Q, M, N) :-
   expr(Q),
   between(0, M, N),
   eval(Q, [], Q, [N], _).
```

Here are some results for the new SWI-Prolog 8.3.17, which
got its unify_with_occurs_check/2 fixed to gether with
zhe occurs check flag fixed:

```
/* explicit unify_with_occurs_check/2 */
?- time((dif(Q, []), quine(Q, 6, N))).
% 208,612,270 inferences, 11.344 CPU in 11.332 seconds (100% CPU, 18390062 Lips)

/* occurs_check=true */
?- time((dif(Q, []), quine(Q, 6, N))).
% 48,502,916 inferences, 2.859 CPU in 2.859 seconds (100% CPU, 16962768 Lips)
```

And also a preview for the upcoming Jekejeke Prolog 1.4.7,
which will also feature an occurs check flag:

```
/* explicit unify_with_occurs_check/2 */
?- time((dif(Q, []), quine(Q, 6, N))).
% Up 37,988 ms, GC 334 ms, Threads 37,625 ms (Current 01/10/21 01:29:35)

/* occurs_check=true */
?- time((dif(Q, []), quine(Q, 6, N))).
% Up 13,367 ms, GC 99 ms, Threads 13,235 ms (Current 01/10/21 01:35:24)
```

Quite amazing that the occurs check flag can lead to a 3-fold spead-up in both Prolog systems! The result is possibly indicative the way we explicitly placed unify_with_occurs_check/2 was faulty?

BTW: Open source:

**Quine Generation via Relational Interpreters**
explicit unify_with_occurs_check/2
https://gist.github.com/jburse/a05e04191dcc68e542567542a7183d3b#file-quine-pl

**Quine Generation via Relational Interpreters**
occurs_check=true
https://gist.github.com/jburse/a05e04191dcc68e542567542a7183d3b#file-quine2-pl

Comment: These gists are now no longer available. Could you update with their new locations?