# Proper unify_with_occurs_check/2 in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, logical-purity, occurs-check

Got this strange behaviour. I was running these test cases:

```
s1 :-
   Q=[[lambda,symbol(_3026),[cons,[quote,_3434],
     [quote,_3514]]],[quote,_3206]],
   P=[_3434|_3514],
   freeze(_3434, (write(foo), nl)),
   unify_with_occurs_check(P, Q).

s2 :-
   Q=[[lambda,symbol(_3026),[cons,[quote,_3434],
     [quote,_3514]]],[quote,_3206]],
   P=[_3434|_3514],
   freeze(_3434, (write(foo), nl)),
   freeze(_3514, (write(bar), nl)),
   unify_with_occurs_check(P, Q).
```

Now I get these results, where the outcome of `s2` is wrong. The outcome is wrong in two respects, first `_3434` gets triggered and second `unify_with_occurs_check` succeeds:

```
SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.3.16)

?- s1.
false.

?- s2.
foo
bar
true.
```

That `_3434` shouldn't get triggered follows from 7.3.2 Herband Algorithm in ISO core standard. According to clause 7.3.2 f) 1) an instantiation of variable X to a term t is only propagated when it X does not occur in t.

That the unification should fail follows from clause 7.3.2 g). So it seems in SWI-Prolog, attributed variables in various incarnations such as freeze/2, dif/2, etc… seem to interfer with unify_with_occurs_check.

Any workaround?

**Edit 06.02.2021:**
The [bug](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/issues/758) has been fixed in SWI-Prolog 8.3.17 (devel) and
was backported to SWI-Prolog 8.2.4 (stable) as well.

Comment: What about reducing the examples in size and improving it in readability?

Comment: Works in Scryer and SICStus.

Comment: Has nothing to do with poor `dif/2`: `freeze(A,true),freeze(B,true),unify_with_occurs_check(A-B,s(A,B)-n).`

Comment: @false So is this a bug?

Comment: @MaxB: Indeed, it is a bug. The most simplistic argument (that does not refer to any of the details) is: Take above query and compare it to the same query but without one of the freeze-goals. Removing a goal should not make the query fail, but it does.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another somewhat simpler workaround:

```
unify(X,X) :-
   acyclic_term(X).
```

Certainly, this only works as expected if the two arguments are finite from the very start, but at least it does not loop in this case.

Comment: This particular requirement was not stated in the question.

Comment: This solution would violate 7.3.2 f) 1) from ISO core standard.

Answer (score 2):

One way out could be to roll your own unify_with_occurs_check/2. We can write it in Prolog itself, as was done in the past, for Prolog systems that did not have unify_with_occurs_check/2:

> R.A.O'Keefe, 15 September 1984
> http://www.picat-lang.org/bprolog/publib/metutl.html

Here is an alternative take that uses (=..)/2 and term_variables/2:

```
unify(X, Y) :- var(X), var(Y), !, X = Y.
unify(X, Y) :- var(X), !, notin(X, Y), X = Y.
unify(X, Y) :- var(Y), !, notin(Y, X), X = Y.
unify(X, Y) :- functor(X, F, A), functor(Y, G, B),
   F/A = G/B,
   X =.. [_|L],
   Y =.. [_|R],
   maplist(unify, L, R).

notin(X, Y) :-
   term_variables(Y, L),
   maplist(\==(X), L).
```

I now get the expected result:

```
?- s1.
false.

?- s2.
false.
```