# Simulating occurs_check=error in SICStus Prolog

Tags: prolog, sicstus-prolog, occurs-check

It turns out that SICStus Prolog doesn't have an occurs_check
Prolog flag. At least we couldn't find one, and this here
gives an error message:

```
/* SICStus 4.6.0 (x86_64-win32-nt-4) */

?- set_prolog_flag(occurs_check, true).
Domain error in argument 1 of set_prolog_flag/2
```

It seems the value "true" is not so much a problem, the
crictical unifications can be realized via the existing
built-in `unify_with_occurs_check/2`. An interesting value
of an occurs_check Prolog flag is the value "error".

How would one implement a predicate `unify_with_occurs_check_and_error/2` ?
Please note, the solution for unify_with_occurs_check_and_error/2
should behave like unify_with_occurs_check/2, i.e. not trigger
attributed variables.

Here is an example usage of the Prolog flag where present:

```
?- set_prolog_flag(occurs_check, error).
true.

?- X = f(X).
ERROR: ...
```

And this is what one would do in SICStus Prolog:

```
?- unify_with_occurs_check_and_error(X, f(X)).
ERROR: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Was adapting the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65533141/502187) and got the following solution:

```
unify_with_error(X, Y) :- var(X), var(Y), !, X = Y.
unify_with_error(X, Y) :- var(X), !, must_notin(X, Y), X = Y.
unify_with_error(X, Y) :- var(Y), !, must_notin(Y, X), X = Y.
unify_with_error(X, Y) :- functor(X, F, A), functor(Y, G, B),
   F/A = G/B,
   X =.. [_|L],
   Y =.. [_|R],
   maplist(unify_with_error, L, R).

must_notin(X, Y) :-
   term_variables(Y, L),
   maplist(\==(X), L), !.
must_notin(X, Y) :-
   throw(error(occurs_check(X, Y),_)).
```

Seems to work and no interference with attributed variables:

```
/* SICStus 4.6.0 (x86_64-win32-nt-4) */

?- unify_with_error(X, f(X)). 
error(occurs_check(_413,f(_413)),_409)

?- freeze(X, throw(ball)), unify_with_error(X, f(X)).
error(occurs_check(_413,f(_413)),_409)
```